# Elasticsearch search keyword ignoring empty query values

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version:

we would like to build a query like the following

```
......
......
bool: {
 must: [
   match : {
      myfield.myfield2.keyword : {
         query: "myvalue"
      }
   }
 ]
}
......
......
```

How can we modify the above one in a way that:

- "myvalue" is an empty string: we would like that elasticsearch ignores it instead of searching for empty string
- "myvalue" not empty. We should get the exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this check in your application code while building the query, if  `myvalue` is empty or null, you don't add the query.

If that's not possible for any reason, there's a way to do this in Elasticsearch using [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) which are built using the [Mustache templating language](https://mustache.github.io/).

Basically, your query would look like this, where the `match` query is only added if `myvalue` has a non-null, non-false, non-empty value:

```
POST _scripts/my-query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {{#myvalue}}
            {
              "match" : {
                "myfield.myfield2.keyword" : {
                  "query": "myvalue"
                }
              }
            }
            {{/myvalue}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    """
  }
}
```

If you call this search template with a null, false, empty value, then the `match` query is not added

```
POST _render/template
{
  "id": "my-query",
  "params": {
    "myvalue": ""
  }
}
```

=>

```
  {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Whereas if you call it with a non-null, non-false, non-empty value, the `match` query is added:

```
POST _render/template
{
  "id": "my-query",
  "params": {
    "myvalue": "test"
  }
}
```

=>

```
  {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [
          {
            "match" : {
              "myfield.myfield2.keyword" : {
                "query" : "myvalue"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try